# Why newly created Python object has value of previous

Tags: python, constructor

Why this code:

```
class B:
    val = []

for i in range(0, 5):
    obj = B()
    print(obj.val)
    obj.val.append('a')
```

has such output?

```
[]
['a']
['a', 'a']
['a', 'a', 'a']
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

In each iteration new B object is created. Why it has value of previous one?

Comment: You're modifying a class attribute not instance attribute.

Comment: Because `val` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Comment: how should I modify instance attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're modifying a class attribute not instance attribute. Change `val` to an instance attribute:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided example of how to use [static variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) in python. Answer to question ["Static class variables in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/2419207) explains how to achieve what you have done. It looks like every coin has two sides.

Python Programming FAQ explains such behaviour in detail: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-static-class-data-and-static-class-methods